# Jasmine inject beforeEach is being ignored

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Using Angular 1.5.6 and angular-mocks@1.5.6

Here is a stripped down version of my spec file:

```
describe('Controller: blahCtrl', function() {

  var blahCtrl;
  var rootScope;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('blahModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    console.log('inject beforeEach is hit'); // does not log
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    blahCtrl = $controller('blahCtrl as vm', {
      $scope: scope,
      $rootScope: rootScope
    });
  }));

  describe('blahMethod()', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      console.log('describe beforeEach is hit'); // logs
    });

    it('does something', function() {
      console.log('describe it block is hit'); // logs
    });
  });
});
```

What could be the reason why my inject beforeEach is never hit? Surely this should be fine?

Comment: Do you receive any errors?, and for your beforeEach module function use;
beforeEach(function(){module("app");});

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. The issue was that I was calling a service's method in the module's run block - this was causing the inject to fail. Fixed issue with run block using info from here [link](http://blog.andre-eife.com/2015/02/10/test-run-and-config-blocks.html)